# cursor.update(val) OR put(val, id)?

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

Using cursor:

```
indexedDB.open('my-db').onsuccess = event =>
    event.target.result
        .transaction('my-object-store', 'readwrite')
        .objectStore('my-object-store')
        .openCursor(bound).onsuccess = event => {
            event.target.result.update(val)
        }
```

Using `put()`:

```
indexedDB.open('my-db').onsuccess = event =>
    event.target.result
        .transaction('my-object-store', 'readwrite')
        .objectStore('my-object-store')
        .put(val, id);
```

In my case I need to update not the whole value but only part of stored object - so I will get the object-value first, alter and persist it.

Semantically `update` better describe than `put`, but maybe some other caveats? Something about performance? What the difference between update through the cursor and put()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference in behavior (performance, etc) between `put()` and `update()`. The `update()` method is just a convenience when iterating with a cursor, and avoids having to specify an explicit key.